When running list.Sort(), 'NullReferenceException' error occurs
public class SortTest
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int age;
        public int grade;
        public Student(int age, int grade)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.grade = grade;
        }
    }

    public List<Student> list = new List<Student>();

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            list.Add(new Student(0, 0));

        list.Sort(delegate (Student A, Student B)
        {
            if (A.grade > B.grade)
                return 1;
            else if (A.grade < B.grade)
                return -1;
            else
            {
                if (A.age > B.age)
                    return 1;
                return -1;
            }
        });
    }
}

public static void Main(){
    SortTest s = new SortTest();
    s.Run();
}

When running the above code, error occur at including this code(if (A.grade > B.grade)) line.
I'm wondering why this error occurs.
list.Add(new Student(0, 0)); It's just for testing.

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) ; ? Huh?

@ProgrammingLlama Sorry, It's just testing code. I'll remove it.

At a guess, you're causing a problem by never returning 0.

Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-comparison((-0)))

If I run your code there is no null reference exception. There is however an argument exception due to your sort method being inconsistent. System.ArgumentException: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results.

I just tested with adding a returning 0 code, It's working well. Thank you

Everyone, Thanks for helping, I'll check the document more.

@Karl I got a null reference exception when I ran it.

@Karl Here. It is the inner exception of an InvalidOperationException, but the internal ArraySortHelper is passing a null instance of Student to the comparer function.

Not sure if this can be considered an answer but whenever you implement an interface, make sure to comply by its contract: _"Returns
Int32
A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y:

If less than 0, x is less than y.
If 0, x equals y.
If greater than 0, x is greater than y."_ - Documentation (emphasis by me - that's what's missing)


You might want to read Writing a sort comparison function. I think it does a better job of spelling out the requirements than the official documentation.

@MarcGravell OP seems to be trying to order by age in the case students have same grade though, so maybe a.grade != b.grade ? a.grade - b.grade : a.age - b.age  instead

"it does a better job of spelling out the requirements than the official documentation" - which is actually kind of sad but true @JonasH
